# Geometric morphisms and essential geometric morphisms

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Let $C$ and $D$ be sites. Each morphism of sites $f : C \rightarrow D$ gives an essential geometric morphism $f_! \dashv f^* \dashv f_* : [C^{op}, \text{Set}]_{\text{Cat}} \rightarrow [D^{op}, \text{Set}]_{\text{Cat}}$.

We also get an adjunction $f_* : \text{Sh}(C) \rightarrow \text{Sh}(D): f^*$, but not necessarily a $f_!$ here. From what I understand, geometric morphisms arose when people tried to encapsulate the properties of $f_*$ and $f^*$ here; the adjunction $f_* \dashv f^*$ always has the extra property that $f^*$ preserves finite limits. Further, embeddings are characterized as embeddings of sheaf categories into their presheaf categories, up to natural isomorphism.

On the other hand, we could try to synthesize this setup in another way: there are geometric embeddings $\text{Sh}(C) \rightarrow [C^{op}, \text{Set}]$ and $\text{Sh}(D) \rightarrow [D^{op}, \text{Set}]$, making a commutative diagram:

[image]

In this diagram, the top adjunction is an essential geometric morphism, and the vertical adjunctioins are geometric embeddings. The right adjoints of make a commutative diagram, so that the left adjoints commute up to natural isomorphism. Further, the top and vertical left adjoinits preserve finite limits, from which we can see that the bottom does as well.

My question is, could we equally well define a geometric morphism of grothendieck topoi to be one which arises from a setup such as this?

Comment: This seems to be essentially the question of whether every geometric morphism between Grothendieck toposes arises from a morphism of sites. The right adjoint in a geometric morphism is always accessible, so the left adjoint preserves $\lambda$-presentable objects for some $\lambda$. I’m tempted to say that if $\lambda$ is big enough, since a Grothendieck topos has a generator, then the $\lambda$-presentable objects must be a presenting site, but I’ve never really thought about whether this is true.

Comment: @KevinArlin It is true. The idea is that the category of sheaves is the completion of the site under colimits, subject to certain preservation conditions. The situation is simplified a lot when the site has finite limits, but in any locally presentable category, the full subcategory of $\lambda$-presentable objects is closed under finite limits for $\lambda$ large enough. At any rate, the whole topos itself is a presenting site, albeit a large one.